# filling forward conditional result

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a DataFrame with columns `A` and `B`. Now I want to produce column `C` like this:

```
       A   B   C
index  
 1     0   50   NaN
 2     1   60   60
 3     0   40   60
 4     0   30   60 
 5     1   40   40
```

`C` gets the value of `B` if `A==1` in this row. Then this value is kept in coming rows until next time `A==1`.How can I do this in vectorized fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the values of B where A==1, then fill forward:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"A":[0,1,0,0,1], "B":[50,60,40,30,40]}, index=[1,2,3,4,5])
a["C"] = a.B[a.A == 1]
a = a.fillna(method="ffill")
```

The ffill method propagates forward the last valid observation to fill in the NaNs. See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html for more info.

This gives:

```
   A   B   C
1  0  50 NaN
2  1  60  60
3  0  40  60
4  0  30  60
5  1  40  40
```

Answer (score 1):

alternative method, one-liner, which seems to be bit faster:

```
In [301]: df['C'] = pd.Series(np.where(df.A==1, df.B, np.nan), index=df.index).ffill()

In [302]: df
Out[302]:
   A   B     C
1  0  50   NaN
2  1  60  60.0
3  0  40  60.0
4  0  30  60.0
5  1  40  40.0
```

Setup 500K rows DF:

```
In [310]: %paste
def method1(a):
    a["C"] = a.B[a.A == 1]
    return a.fillna(method="ffill")

def method2(df):
    df['C'] = pd.Series(np.where(df.A==1, df.B, np.nan), index=df.index).ffill()
    return df
## -- End pasted text --

df = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [313]: df.shape
Out[313]: (500000, 2)
```

Timing:

```
In [311]: %timeit method1(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 95.3 ms per loop

In [312]: %timeit method2(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.8 ms per loop
```

Interesting, i thought that @Seabass's method should be faster, but apparently it's not ...